# How can I authenticate a user with their AD credentials over a C# WCF web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I am writing a small bootstrapping utility to set up users' laptops. It will be WPF and will be available from a publicly accessible website. (The utility will join the laptop to the domain and perform a bunch of setup steps.) It will use an internet facing web-service for any communication between the utility and the main server.

I obviously need to ensure that only authorised users can run this, and plan to authenticate using the webservice. (I'm thinking of a username / password box in which users enter their AD credentials, and then click "Go" to start the process.)

How can I use their AD credentials in this way to authenticate them? (At the point they start the utility they will be off the domain, and just connected to the internet.)

Comment: Why don't you look at using `PrincipalContext` also you can do this using javascript which you could use javascript prompt() method to display a input box where the use could enter in their domain username. there are also many other ways to do this .. try doing some googling

Comment: Thanks @MethodMan - PrincipalContext did the trick